# LibGdx font.setColor(Color.WHITE) isnt working

Tags: java, libgdx

```
public void show()
{
    buttonsAtlas = new TextureAtlas("spellButton.pack"); //button atlas image
    buttonSkin = new Skin();
    buttonSkin.addRegions(buttonsAtlas);
    font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("WhiteAlpha.fnt"), false); //the font
    font.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    stage = new Stage(); // window is stage
    stage.clear();

    TextButton.TextButtonStyle ribbonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle(); //Shop title ribbon properties
    ribbonStyle.up = buttonSkin.getDrawable("ribbon");
    ribbonStyle.down = buttonSkin.getDrawable("ribbon");
    ribbonStyle.font = font;

    ribbon = new TextButton("SHOP", ribbonStyle);  //shop title outlook adn textstyle
    ribbon.setPosition(200, 1720);
    ribbon.setSize(880, 200);
```

}

I want to print the letter "SHOP" within the image. However the image is in a dark gray color, so I am trying to print the letter "SHOP" in white as font.setColor(Color.WHITE) but this is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ribbonStyle.fontColor` instead.

```
public void show()
{
    buttonsAtlas = new TextureAtlas("spellButton.pack"); //button atlas image
    buttonSkin = new Skin();
    buttonSkin.addRegions(buttonsAtlas);
    font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("WhiteAlpha.fnt"), false); //the font

    stage = new Stage(); // window is stage
    stage.clear();

    TextButton.TextButtonStyle ribbonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle(); //Shop title ribbon properties
    ribbonStyle.up = buttonSkin.getDrawable("ribbon");
    ribbonStyle.down = buttonSkin.getDrawable("ribbon");
    ribbonStyle.font = font;

    // change it here (per style)
->  ribbonStyle.fontColor = Color.WHITE;

    ribbon = new TextButton("SHOP", ribbonStyle);  //shop title outlook adn textstyle
    ribbon.setPosition(200, 1720);
    ribbon.setSize(880, 200);

    // or, you can change it here (per button)
->  ribbon.setColor(Color.WHITE); 

}
```

Comment: this doesnt fix my issue.. the word "SHOP" is still shown in black. I generate my font through AngelCode if this helps :(

Comment: @Yukii is your font texture black? The font texture should be white, because you can make white to be colour, but can make colour to be white.

Comment: @Yukii like I said, you can't make black texture to be white, it's nature of colour. Make original texture to be white, and do `setColor(Color.BLACK)` whenever you need it to be black. Same applies to `setColor(Color.WHITE)`